# How can I update custom properties in alfresco workflow task using only Java?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

First, I want to say thanks to everyone that took their time to help me figure this out because I was searching for more than a week for a solution to my problem. Here it is:

My goal is to start a custom workflow in Alfresco Community 5.2 and to set some custom properties in the first task trough a web script using only the Public Java API. My class is extending AbstractWebScript. Currently I have success with starting the workflow and setting properties like bpm:workflowDescription, but I'm not able to set my custom properties in the tasks.

Here is the code:

```
    public class StartWorkflow extends AbstractWebScript {
    /**
     * The Alfresco Service Registry that gives access to all public content services in Alfresco.
     */
    private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public void setServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        this.serviceRegistry = serviceRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(WebScriptRequest req, WebScriptResponse res) throws IOException {       

        // Create JSON object for the response
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        try {                        
            // Check if parameter defName is present in the request            
            String wfDefFromReq = req.getParameter("defName");
            if (wfDefFromReq == null) {
                obj.put("resultCode", "1 (Error)");
                obj.put("errorMessage", "Parameter defName not found.");
                return;      
            }            
            // Get the WFL Service
            WorkflowService workflowService = serviceRegistry.getWorkflowService();
            // Build WFL Definition name
            String wfDefName = "activiti$" + wfDefFromReq;
            // Get WorkflowDefinition object
            WorkflowDefinition wfDef = workflowService.getDefinitionByName(wfDefName);
            // Check if such WorkflowDefinition exists
            if (wfDef == null) {
                obj.put("resultCode", "1 (Error)");
                obj.put("errorMessage", "No workflow definition found for defName = " + wfDefName);
                return;
            }                       

            // Get parameters from the request
            Content reqContent = req.getContent();
            if (reqContent == null) {
                throw new WebScriptException(Status.STATUS_BAD_REQUEST, "Missing request body.");
            }
            String content;
            content = reqContent.getContent();

            if (content.isEmpty()) {
                throw new WebScriptException(Status.STATUS_BAD_REQUEST, "Content is empty");
            }

            JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(content);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);           

            // Set the workflow description
            Map<QName, Serializable> params = new HashMap();
            params.put(WorkflowModel.PROP_WORKFLOW_DESCRIPTION, "Workflow started from JAVA API");          

            // Start the workflow
            WorkflowPath wfPath = workflowService.startWorkflow(wfDef.getId(), params);

            // Get params from the POST request
            Map<QName, Serializable> reqParams = new HashMap();
            Iterator<String> i = json.keys();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                String paramName = i.next();
                QName qName = QName.createQName(paramName);
                String value = json.getString(qName.getLocalName());
                reqParams.put(qName, value);  
            }

            // Try to update the task properties

            // Get the next active task which contains the properties to update
            WorkflowTask wfTask = workflowService.getTasksForWorkflowPath(wfPath.getId()).get(0);
            // Update properties
            WorkflowTask updatedTask = workflowService.updateTask(wfTask.getId(), reqParams, null, null);

            obj.put("resultCode", "0 (Success)");
            obj.put("workflowId", wfPath.getId());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new WebScriptException(Status.STATUS_BAD_REQUEST, 
                    e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new WebScriptException(Status.STATUS_BAD_REQUEST, 
                    "Error when parsing the request.", 
                    ioe);
        } finally {
            // build a JSON string and send it back
            String jsonString = obj.toString();
            res.getWriter().write(jsonString);
        }

    }  
}
```

Here is how I call the webscript:

```
curl -v -uadmin:admin -X POST -d @postParams.json localhost:8080/alfresco/s/workflow/startJava?defName=nameOfTheWFLDefinition -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

In postParams.json file I have the required pairs for property/value which I need to update:

```
{
"cmprop:propOne" : "Value 1",
"cmprop:propTwo" : "Value 2",
"cmprop:propThree" : "Value 3"
```

}

The workflow is started, bpm:workflowDescription is set correctly, but the properties in the task are not visible to be set.

I made a JS script which I call when the workflow is started:

```
execution.setVariable('bpm_workflowDescription', 'Some String ' + execution.getVariable('cmprop:propOne'));
```

And actually the value for cmprop:propOne is used and the description is properly updated - which means that those properties are updated somewhere (on execution level maybe?) but I cannot figure out why they are not visible when I open the task.

I had success with starting the workflow and updating the properties using the JavaScript API with:

```
if (wfdef) {

        // Get the params
        wfparams = {};
        if (jsonRequest) {
            for ( var prop in jsonRequest) {
                wfparams[prop] = jsonRequest[prop];
            }
        }

        wfpackage = workflow.createPackage();

        wfpath = wfdef.startWorkflow(wfpackage, wfparams);
```

The problem is that I only want to use the public Java API, please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you set your variables locally in your tasks? From what I see, it seems that you define your variables at the execution level, but not at the state level. If you take a look at the ootb adhoc.bpmn20.xml file (https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti-Designer/blob/master/org.activiti.designer.eclipse/src/main/resources/templates/adhoc.bpmn20.xml), you can notice an event listener that sets the variable locally:

```
<extensionElements>
    <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
       <activiti:field name="script">
          <activiti:string>
           if (typeof bpm_workflowDueDate != 'undefined') task.setVariableLocal('bpm_dueDate', bpm_workflowDueDate);
           if (typeof bpm_workflowPriority != 'undefined') task.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;
          </activiti:string>
       </activiti:field>
    </activiti:taskListener>
</extensionElements>
```

Comment: I've tried with:
`if (typeof cmprop_propOne != 'undefined') task.setVariableLocal('cmprop_propOne', execution.getVariable('cmprop_propOne'));` but still with no success. What am I missing?

Comment: I've tried to use task.setVariable and task.setVariableLocal both with no success. It appears that for some reason when using javascript all properties are visible both on execution and task level, but when I use the Java API the properties are only visible on execution level :?
Also, `workflowService.updateTask(wfTask.getId(), reqParams, null, null);` for some reason also doesn't make the properties visible.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I just try to import all tasks for my custom model prefix. So for you, it should look like that:

```
import java.util.Set;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateTask;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ImportVariables extends AbstractTaskListener {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ImportVariables.class);

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask task) {

        logger.debug("Inside ImportVariables.notify()");
        logger.debug("Task ID:" + task.getId());
        logger.debug("Task name:" + task.getName());
        logger.debug("Task proc ID:" + task.getProcessInstanceId());
        logger.debug("Task def key:" + task.getTaskDefinitionKey());

        DelegateExecution execution = task.getExecution();

        Set<String> executionVariables = execution.getVariableNamesLocal();
        for (String variableName : executionVariables) {
            // If the variable starts by "cmprop_"
            if (variableName.startsWith("cmprop_")) {
                // Publish it at the task level
                task.setVariableLocal(variableName, execution.getVariableLocal(variableName));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Ben for these answers. I've tried this, but I had to use  `ImportVariables extends BaseJavaDelegate implements TaskListener`. 
Actually, after some more tests I've made I found out something really odd:
It appears that even without this listener the properties are being updated, but for some reason Alfresco is not showing them ?!? 
I did the following test: started a workflow using the webscript,  then I checked the task and nothing was populated. Then, I just restarted the app server and without doing anything else when I checked the same task - the properties were visible...

Comment: Also, If I start another workflow with the webscript then the properties disappear again, for both the previously started workflow and the new one until I restart the app server. After the restart, properties for both workflows  are visible in the tasks. Do you or anyone have an idea why this can be happening?